# How can i check that the pictureBox i'm moving around will not get out the borders top left right bottom of the second picturebox area?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void picZoom_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PicImageClicked == false)
            {
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    int x = e.X + picZoom.Left - picImage.Left;
                    int y = e.Y + picZoom.Top - picImage.Top;
                    if (x <= picImage.Width && y <= picImage.Height &&
                        x <= picImage.Top && y <= picImage.Left)
                    {
                        MouseEventArgs e2 = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, x, y, 0);
                        picImageReposition(null, e2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateZoomedImage(e);
                }
            }
        }
```

picImage is a bigger pictureBox and picZoom is a smaller pictureBox the picZoom i'm moving aorund inside the picImage are with the mouse.

This condition:

```
if (x <= picImage.Width && y <= picImage.Height
```

Is working if i'm moving the picZoom to the left border or the bottom border it stop on it and not continue.

But the second condition:

```
x <= picImage.Top && y <= picImage.Left
```

Is not working good it make everything slow and it's not stopping on the left or top borders.

I want to make a condition/s so the picZoom will stay in the picImage area borders.

What i tried now is:

```
private void picZoom_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pnt;
            int x, y;

            if (MouseButtons.Left == e.Button)
            {
                pnt = picZoom.PointToScreen(e.Location);
                pnt = this.PointToClient(pnt);

                x = pnt.X - mouseDown.X;
                y = pnt.Y - mouseDown.Y;

                if (x < picImage.Left)
                {
                    x = picImage.Left;
                }
                else if (x + picZoom.Width > picImage.Left + picImage.Width)
                {
                    x = picImage.Left + picImage.Width - picZoom.Width;
                }
                else
                { }

                if (y < picImage.Top)
                {
                    y = picImage.Top;
                }
                else if (y + picZoom.Height > picImage.Top + picImage.Height)
                {
                    y = picImage.Top + picImage.Height - picZoom.Height;
                }
                else
                { }

                picZoom.Location = new Point(x, y);


                if (PicImageClicked == false)
                {
                    if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    {

                        MouseEventArgs e2 = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, x, y, 0);
                        picImageReposition(null, e2);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UpdateZoomedImage(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

picImageReposition is:

```
private void picImageReposition(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // If no picture is loaded, return
            if (picImage.Image == null)
                return;

            if (PicImageClicked == false)
            {

                picZoom.BringToFront();
                picZoom.Left = e.X + picImage.Left - picZoom.Width/2;
                picZoom.Top = e.Y + picImage.Top - picZoom.Height/2;
                UpdateZoomedImage(e);
            }
        }
```

And UpdateZoomedImage is:

```
private void UpdateZoomedImage(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate the width and height of the portion of the image we want
            // to show in the picZoom picturebox. This value changes when the zoom
            // factor is changed.
            int zoomWidth = picZoom.Width / _ZoomFactor;
            int zoomHeight = picZoom.Height / _ZoomFactor;

            // Calculate the horizontal and vertical midpoints for the crosshair
            // cursor and correct centering of the new image
            int halfWidth = zoomWidth / 2;
            int halfHeight = zoomHeight / 2;

            // Create a new temporary bitmap to fit inside the picZoom picturebox
            tempBitmap = new Bitmap(zoomWidth, zoomHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            // Create a temporary Graphics object to work on the bitmap
            Graphics bmGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);

            // Clear the bitmap with the selected backcolor
            bmGraphics.Clear(_BackColor);

            // Set the interpolation mode
            bmGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            // Draw the portion of the main image onto the bitmap
            // The target rectangle is already known now.
            // Here the mouse position of the cursor on the main image is used to
            // cut out a portion of the main image.
            bmGraphics.DrawImage(picImage.Image,
                                 new Rectangle(0, 0, zoomWidth, zoomHeight),
                                 new Rectangle(e.X - halfWidth, e.Y - halfHeight, zoomWidth, zoomHeight),
                                 GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


            // Draw the bitmap on the picZoom picturebox
            picZoom.Image = tempBitmap;

            // Draw a crosshair on the bitmap to simulate the cursor position
            bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight - 4, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight - 1);
            bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight + 6, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight + 3);
            bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth - 4, halfHeight + 1, halfWidth - 1, halfHeight + 1);
            bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 6, halfHeight + 1, halfWidth + 3, halfHeight + 1);

            // Dispose of the Graphics object
            bmGraphics.Dispose();

            // Refresh the picZoom picturebox to reflect the changes
            picZoom.Refresh();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the formula of moving the *picZoom* control is what you want eg

```
int x = e.X + picZoom.Left - picImage.Left;
int y = e.Y + picZoom.Top - picImage.Top;
```

then the comparison is(x, y is the position in picImage meaning that 0,0 is the left top position):

```
if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x + picZoom.Width <= picImage.Width && y + picZoom.Height <= picImage.Height)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

When you click in *picZoom* and drag, the control moves with the mouse:

```
private Point mouseDown;

private void picZoom_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = e.Location;
}

private void picZoom_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point pnt;
    int x, y;

    if (MouseButtons.Left == e.Button)
    {
        pnt = picZoom.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        pnt = this.PointToClient(pnt);

        x = pnt.X - mouseDown.X;
        y = pnt.Y - mouseDown.Y;

        if (x < picImage.Left)
        {
            x = picImage.Left;
        }
        else if (x + picZoom.Width > picImage.Left + picImage.Width)
        {
            x = picImage.Left + picImage.Width - picZoom.Width;
        }
        else
        { }

        if (y < picImage.Top)
        {
            y = picImage.Top;
        }
        else if (y + picZoom.Height > picImage.Top + picImage.Height)
        {
            y = picImage.Top + picImage.Height - picZoom.Height;
        }
        else
        { }

        picZoom.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

valter

Comment: It's not moving smooth to the right and bottom now. When in my question my first code when i used the first condition only for the Width and Height(x <= picImage.Width && y <= picImage.Height) it was moving smooth and fine to the right and bottom and stopped on borders right and bottom then i  added my second condition so it was moving slow stuttering to the left and top now when i'm trying your solution it's moving smooth and good to the left and top but slow and stuttering to the right and bottom.

Comment: @yairshalvi The smoothness has nothing to do with the comparison. Do you want *picZoom* location to be the same with the mouse cursor? Is *picZoom* a child of *picImage*?

Comment: yes and picZoom is on it's own pictureBox and it is smaller then the picImage and yes i'm moving with the mouse the picZoom over the picImage. It's moving smotth if i'm not using this conditions but i want to make that the picZoom will not be able to move out of the picImage area.

Comment: This is hte main form code there are no classes just the main form http://pastebin.com/mQ9HhN5C

Comment: This is a link to screenshot of the program. The picZoom the smaller one is inside the picImage the bigger one area. And i drag the small one with the mouse and when i drag it to one of the corners or borders of the picImage left top right bottom it should stop when the +(plus sign) in the picZoom touch the edge/border. http://postimg.org/image/fz1b2b9jd/

Comment: Saw your edited solution and tried now the picZoom is moving slow stuttering. Watch my question please i have updated it with your solution and with the methods i'm using in the picZoom mouse move method. Why it's making it moving slow stuttering when changing or adding conditions to the picZoom mouse move event ?

Comment: @yairshalvi You are calling *UpdateZoomedImage* for every move event! So, if you move your mouse 100 pixels in 500msec, *UpdateZoomedImage* will be called 100 times, 100 *tempBitmap's* will be created without disposing them, 400 lines and 100 bitmaps will be drawn etc... Do you think that GDI+ is capable of doing what you are trying to do? Have you ever try to measure the time needed to draw a single image?

Comment: @yairshalvi Think before writing code. You can not load a ten year child with 100kgrs and expect him to carry them, and then complain that the drawing is slow. Be more carefull. Clean your code.

Comment: You are right i will clean and fix my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question as much as it is a suggestion. Could you not create a Rect() directly over your picture and simply check if the mouse position is within it's bounds.

Something along the lines of:

```
Rectangle rect = obj.GetBounds(e.Graphics);
      if (!rect.Intersects(e.ClipRectangle))
         continue;
```

(stolen from another post)

Answer (score 0):

So I looked over your code again, and it struck me.

You are comparing an x value to the top bound of your picture and a y value to the left bound...

```
x <= picImage.Top && y <= picImage.Left
```

should be

```
x <= picImage.Left && y <= picImage.Top
```

That is, if I understand what you are trying to do.

Good luck!

Comment: You could edit your first answer instead of having two.